# Creating Postgres View getting ERROR: column "id" specified more than once

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, sql-view

**SCENARIO:**

I have this select statement that `JOIN`s a bunch of tables together:

```
SELECT 
    e0.id, e0.name, e0.slug,
    e1.id, e1.edition, e1.url, e1.date, e1.event_id,
    v2.id, v2.title, v2.language, v2.description, v2.provider, v2.videoid, v2.image_url, v2.event_id, v2.edition_id,
    s3.id, s3.name, s3.twitter, s3.website
FROM 
    events AS e0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    editions AS e1 ON e1.event_id = e0.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    videos AS v2 ON v2.edition_id = e1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    videos_speakers AS v4 ON v4.video_id = v2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    speakers AS s3 ON v4.speaker_id = s3.id
ORDER BY 
    e1.date DESC;
```

I'd like to create a [Postgres View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html). So wrote it out like this:

```
CREATE VIEW all_events 
AS
    SELECT 
        e0.id, e0.name, e0.slug,
        e1.id, e1.edition, e1.url, e1.date, e1.event_id,
        v2.id, v2.title, v2.language, v2.description, v2.provider, v2.videoid, v2.image_url, v2.event_id, v2.edition_id,
        s3.id, s3.name, s3.twitter, s3.website
    FROM 
        events AS e0 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        editions AS e1 ON e1.event_id = e0.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        videos AS v2 ON v2.edition_id = e1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        videos_speakers AS v4 ON v4.video_id = v2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        speakers AS s3 ON v4.speaker_id = s3.id
    ORDER BY 
        e1.date DESC;
```

I keep getting this error:

> ERROR:  column "id" specified more than once

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How do I fix this error? I would like to create a view called "all_events".
2. Are [Postgres View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) sort of like aliases in other languages?

New to Postgres, reading the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) but trying to understand the mental model here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several column names that are the same. Even if you select `e0.id` the column is still name (only) `id`.

But in the scope of a view (or table) each column name must be unique.

You need to provide aliases for each duplicate column:

```
CREATE VIEW all_events AS
SELECT  e0.id as event_id, --<< here 
        e0.name as event_name, --<< here 
        e0.slug,
        e1.id as edition_id,  --<< here
        e1.edition, 
        e1.url, 
        e1.date, 
        e1.event_id as edition_event_id, --<< here
        v2.id as video_id,  --<< here
        v2.title, 
        v2.language, 
        v2.description, 
        v2.provider, 
        v2.videoid, 
        v2.image_url, 
        v2.event_id as video_event_id, --<< here 
        v2.edition_id as video_edition_id, --<< here
        s3.id as speaker_id,  --<< here
        s3.name as speaker_name, --<< here 
        s3.twitter, 
        s3.website
FROM events AS e0 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN editions AS e1 ON e1.event_id = e0.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN videos AS v2 ON v2.edition_id = e1.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_speakers AS v4 ON v4.video_id = v2.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN speakers AS s3 ON v4.speaker_id = s3.id;
```

---

Although Postgres allows it, I highly recommend to **not** create a view with an `ORDER BY` statement. If you ever sort the results of that view by a different column, Postgres will  sort the data twice.

Comment: In re: to `ORDER BY` your final sentence you say "Postgres will..." will what? Ignore it.

Thanks for the solution and I have it working now.

Comment: @alenm: ... will sort the data twice (sorry)

Comment: If I want to keep all columns of each table without writing them out explitly, is it possible to work with ``SELECT *`` and use ``tablename.id AS tablename_id`` in  addition? I have to join 3 views which have a lot of columns.

Answer (score 1):

In the view columns are by default named same as columns of query. The error occurs, because column named `id` is defined in all 3 joined tables. You need to provide aliases to differentiate colliding columns, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW all_events AS
SELECT e0.id as e0id, e0.name as e0name, e0.slug,
        e1.id as e1id, e1.edition, e1.url, e1.date, e1.event_id,
        v2.id as e2id, v2.title, v2.language, v2.description, v2.provider, v2.videoid, v2.image_url, v2.event_id, v2.edition_id,
        s3.id as s3id, s3.name as s3name, s3.twitter, s3.website
        FROM events AS e0 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN editions AS e1 ON e1.event_id = e0.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN videos AS v2 ON v2.edition_id = e1.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_speakers AS v4 ON v4.video_id = v2.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN speakers AS s3 ON v4.speaker_id = s3.id
        ORDER BY e1.date DESC;
```